# “Value does not fall within the expected range” when trying to open file in Visual Studio

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2013

When trying to open files with extension `.SQL` I receive the error `Value does not fall within the expected range:

[image: Screenshot showing "Value does not fall within the expected range" error message]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue by:

- Right clicking the file from Solution Explorer
- Selecting `Open With`
- Selecting `Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, T-SQL PDW Editor`
- Clicking `Set as Default`
- Clicking `OK`

Sadly I did not note the default editor before making this change.

Comment: This didn't work for my in TFS 2015 with SQL files. I still have to click manually each time. I'm working in a powershell project, so not sure if it has an issue with it do to this.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015, Powershell project aswell, same issue:  
Double click on any *.sql file within that project will throw that error.
Right click, then selecting whichever editor as one-shot will work everytime, but setting it as default will not prevent the error.